# How do I write a regex that excludes certain file suffixes?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking at the tutorial given here :-

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions

I want to exclude files that end in .pqr.gz and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

e.g., the expected behaviour is :-

```
f1.gz => succeed
f1.abc.pqr => succeed
f1.pqr.gz => fail
f1.abc.gz => succeed
```

The best regex I could come up with was :-

```
r'.*[.](?=[^.]*[.][^.]*)(?!pqr[.]gz$)[^.]*[.][^.]*$'
```

This excludes files that end in .pqr.gz but doesn't for example allow files that are just f1.gz (i.e. first case I wrote above).

Any ideas on how this can be improved?

EDIT :- There are better ways to do this (e.g., using `string.endswith`), but I'm curious about how to do this with a regex purely as an exercise.

Comment: you shouldn't use regexes to check for suffixes.

Comment: `.*(?<!\.pqr\.gz)$`

Comment: @Rawing That works. Can you write that up as an answer (hopefully with an explanation) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

well, TBH, your use of regex seems overkill to me. You could simply do:

```
if not '.pqr.gz' in line:
    print(line)
```

and done.

Actually, "simple" string manipulation can do a lot in just a few simple operations, like:

```
for line in lines:
    file, result = line.split(' => ')
    if file.endswith('.pqr.gz'):
        print("Skipping file {}".format(file), file=sys.stderr)
        continue
    print(file)
    # and you could do something if result == "success" there after!
```

---

as you insist on doing it with regexps:

here's your current regex representation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

And here's a solution as inspired from @rawing suggestion:

```
.*(?<!\.pqr\.gz) =>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: i think i should mention that it's more of a mental exercise in using regexes than for any practical purpose.

Comment: but you want to filter out extensions not being gz or pqr right?

Comment: (too bad the images link are dead… what's happening with debuggex ? ☹)

Answer (score -1):

One thing to be aware of with Python's `re` module is that `re.match` implicitly anchors to the start of the string.

Also, you can match literal periods by escaping them (`\.`), which is probably easier to read (and potentially faster) than putting it in a character class.

For `re.match` the following regex should do the trick:

```
r'.*\.pqr\.gz$'
```

If using `re.search` instead, the regex can be shortened to just this:

```
r'\.pqr\.gz$'
```

Comment: Another thing to be aware of with re.match is that you have to provide your own anchor to the END of the string. There are 2 choices, `\Z` and `$` ... `$` is there as a hangover from perl. Use `\Z`

Comment: Again, `\Z` is only preferable if you explicitly want trailing newlines to be taken into account by the match statement. `$` is not just a hangover from perl, it is a different anchor that is also useful. For example, if you are trying to match to the end of a line rather than the end of a string, especially when using `flags=re.MULTILINE`, `\Z` is the wrong choice.

Comment: Again look at the OP's question ... wants strings that end in "foo", not "foo\n"